# Is there a way of predefining input when running a shell?

Tags: shell, heredoc

When using a shell script file i want to be able to prewrite the input for the configuration.
how can i give the answers automatically?
there are multiple questions with short answers required for example- 'Please select an option: 1, 2 or 3' and provide answer 2. I considered using a heredoc but would this be the most appropriate option?
My example script:

```
./install.sh <<HERE
1
1
2
1
1 2 3
1 2
2
HERE
```

thanks for any help given.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the tool Expect, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I had considered using expect and send but there are huge chunks of text and in some of the questions the text actually changes. Do you know if you can use wildcards with this?